# Silverlight 4: Question & Replies Style Control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, ria

I need to add a functionality in my application to allow users to ask questions and then post replies to that question.  I understand how to do this in ASP.NET, any advice on how this can be accomplished using Silverlight 4/C#?  I want to be able to do it a tree style, with collapse buttons. I think I may need a detail row...?

Any help/direction is appreciated. Much Thanks.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can implement by silverlight as well, in simple way you must have a storage for storing questions and their answers such as database or xml file or ...

too you can use from services (such as wcf services or web services) if you want enhance security or performance

and for design appearance silverlight is good